# Using Jquery in JIRA and Velocity

Tags: jquery, jira, velocity

Having a wierd problem in JIRA at the moment. When Im on the Edit Issue page, If I have this line of code in my velocity template file (edit.vm):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="$req.contextPath/download/resources/com.company.jira.plugins.customer:jqueryautocomplete/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then the down arrows next to the links at the top of the page for 'Dashboards','Projects','Issues' etc... no longer work. However if i remove that line from my velocity template then the arrows start working again.

It is important to note that when i remove this line from my velocity template my jQuery autocomplete input box stops working which is to be expected as I am removing the jquery.js from being included. Also when i include the above line the jQuery autocomplete box works flawlessly, its just that the arrows don't work as stated above. Obviously its crucial that the edit page has this jquery.js script included in a way that the arrows work as well.

Any suggestions/help as to how i can include the jQuery library are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that JIRA already included jQuery Library v1.4.2 so when i went to include a newer library v1.7.1 there was a conflict between the two which would render the JIRA javascript unusable and since the JIRA javascript controlled the dropdown arrows, they no longer worked.

I also had to slightly modify my javascript code to work with the older v1.4.2 jQuery, but all works well now.